# Почему не работает регулярное выражение?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Программа смотрит список каталогов, надо отсеять папки которые начинаются с цифры с точкой

Допустим, есть список:

> 1. OLD
>   2. MINI
>   MyProject1
>   MyProject2
>   MyProject3

Но регулярное выражение почему-то не срабатывает

```
Regex isCategory = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+\. [a-zA-Z]+", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
if(isCategory.IsMatch(item.Name)) {
    textBox.Text += item.Name + " - isCategory\r\n";
} else {
    textBox.Text += item.Name + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Даже простой вариант `^[0-9]+\.` срабатывает у меня.

Comment: Вы же сами указали опцию `IgnorePatternWhitespace` - вот и не совпадает шаблон.

Answer (score 2):

> `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`

Это лишнее.